# Enviar dados para impressão em outra página

Tags: php, html

Estou precisando enviar algumas informações para uma outra página para impressão, já consegui validar as informações, mas não sei como chamar a outra página e imprimir os dados fornecidos pelo usuário.
O que tenho é isso:

A validação:

```
$(function() {

  $('#frmCadastro').validate({
    rules: {
      Unicoop: {
        required: true
      },
      Empregado: {
        required: true
      },
      CTPS: {
        required: true
      },
      SCTPS: {
        required: true
      },
      Dias: {
        required: true
      },
      Data: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    // Messages for form validation
    messages: {
      Unicoop: {
        required: ''
      },
      Empregado: {
        required: ''
      },
      CTPS: {
        required: ''
      },
      SCTPS: {
        required: ''
      },
      Dias: {
        required: ''
      },
      Data: {
        required: ''
      }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var data = $(form).serialize();
      //event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "pImprimeTermoProrrogacao.php",
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
      return false;

    }
  });

});
```

O meu console.log() me mostra o que precisa estar na outra página para impressão.

```html
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Por mútuo acordo que fazem a EMPRESA TAL, Estabelecimento NOME EMPRESA, devidamente inscrito no CNPJ sob o nº XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX situado à Rodovia BR 376 Km 395, na cidade de CIDADE, Estado do PR, doravante denominada simplesmente EMPREGADORA, e o Sr Rafaela Santos de Souza, portador da Carteira Profissional nº 2545-89 Série 48512, a seguir denominado simplesmente EMPREGADO, fica o Contrato de Experiência por esta assinado, que deveria vencer nesta data, prorrogado por mais 50 dias, com data definitiva de 08/08/2017.</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: impossível fazer qq teste com os códigos apresentados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você necessita que a informação do PHP seja mandado para impressão.

No lugar do seu console.log troque para o código abaixo:

```
var janela = window.open("","","width=200,height=100"); // abre janela
janela.document.write(data); // escreve a info na janela
janela.focus(); // seleciona a janela
janela.print(); // chama a impressão
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado @Bruno Folle, ajudou muito.

Comment: adventistapr, De nada :)